# get user email after Azure AD authentication in xamarin app

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, claims-based-identity

I need to get the email adress after the user authentication.
I tried to fid this information in the authenticationResult but I just found the user name .. but not the email.
How can I get this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the email on the client-side or the server-side?  If it's the server-side, try checking the x-ms-client-principal-name HTTP header value. If it's the client-side, try making an authenticated request to /.auth/me and you should see all the claims, including the user's email in the JSON response.

Comment: var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, CloudConstants.ApIbaseUrl + "/.auth/me");
 try { var response = client.SendAsync(request); if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var profile = JArray.Parse(responseString.Result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)

Comment: If you cannot see the email address after following the steps above - one of two things may have happened:
A: You are not requesting the proper scopes/permission for your app, so you cannot see the email. When the user logs in, he/she should be seeing something like "this app needs your permission to see your email address on your profile." (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) B: Occasionally, the Microsoft account that was authenticated will not have an email linked to it and the x-ms-client-principal-name will be blank.
Some advice: On the headers you can get the user's access token, if you are using Microsoft live, you can use that access token to make a GET request and see all of the user's profile info that you have asked for. For reference, please see the live api documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659736.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in another answer that this is client side, use the InvokeApi<>() method.  This is discussed in detail in the book here: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/authorization/#obtaining-user-claims

Short version is this code:

```
List<AppServiceIdentity> identities = null;

public async Task<AppServiceIdentity> GetIdentityAsync()
{
    if (client.CurrentUser == null || client.CurrentUser?.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not Authenticated");
    }

    if (identities == null)
    {
        identities = await client.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");
    }

    if (identities.Count > 0)
        return identities[0];
    return null;
}
```

Where AppServiceIdentity is defined like this:

```
public class AppServiceIdentity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "provider_name")]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_claims")]
    public List<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}

public class UserClaim
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "typ")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "val")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the InvokeApiAsync to call it.
are there a token or something like that to find the email ?

var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, CloudConstants.ApIbaseUrl + /.auth/me");

```
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authenticationResult.Token);
        try
        {
            var response = client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var profile = JArray.Parse(responseString.Result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("An error has occurred", "Exception message: " + ee.Message, "Dismiss");
        }
```